# Find out if system startup was initiated by rtc alarm

Tags: linux, startup, power-management

How can I know if a system startup was initiated by an rtc alarm event in linux? I am writing some scripts that handle sleeping/shutdown of my htpc. I want the machine to sleep after recording has finished but only if the last startup was due to rtc alarm.